# Axis rotation issue

Tags: python, image-processing

I have an input image containing some bounding boxes and I'm trying to rotate it so that the bounding boxes would still bound the same objects. Here's an input image:

[image]

The two bounding boxes have the following coordinates:

```py
# box 1
x_min=273
y_min=181
x_max=334
y_max=398

# box 2
x_min =383
y_min =185
x_max =473
y_max =407
```

When the image is rotated by 50 degrees, the new coordinates are computed as follows:

The new coordinates are computed as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

theta = np.deg2rad(50)
xc = 640 / 2 # axis of rotation
yc = 480 / 2 # axis of rotation

x1 = xc + (x_min-xc) * np.cos(theta) - (y_min-yc)*np.sin(theta)
y1 = yc - (x_min-xc) * np.sin(theta) + (y_min-yc)*np.cos(theta)

x2 = xc + (x_max-xc) * np.cos(theta) - (y_min-yc)*np.sin(theta)
y2 = yc - (x_max-xc) * np.sin(theta) + (y_min-yc)*np.cos(theta)

x3 = xc + (x_min-xc) * np.cos(theta) - (y_max-yc)*np.sin(theta)
y3 = yc - (x_min-xc) * np.sin(theta) + (y_max-yc)*np.cos(theta)

x4 = xc + (x_max-xc) * np.cos(theta) - (y_max-yc)*np.sin(theta)
y4 = yc - (x_max-xc) * np.sin(theta) + (y_max-yc)*np.cos(theta)

a = min(x1, x2, x3, x4)
b = min(y1, y2, y3, y4)
c = max(x1, x2, x3, x4)
d = max(y1, y2, y3, y4)      

cv2.rectangle(img, (int(a), int(b)), (int(c), int(d)), (0,255,0), 2)
```

However, the coordinates I get don't appear correct:

```
a=167 b=190 c=374 d=378
a=231 b=86 c=461 d=299
```

[image]
where green boxes are the computed boxes and red boxes are the expected boxes.

Does anyone know why the computed coordinates are so far off?

EDIT:

Code changed to account for all 4 box corners.

Comment: How do you draw these boxes? Please, insert a code that perform it.

Comment: well how DO you want them to appear? can't you just rotate the boxes around the same point you rotated the image ?

Comment: @SlawomirOrlowski I've added that now.

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite I'm trying to bound the same objects after rotation. What I'm doing is to rotate the two box corners and use the smallest and largest coordinates as the opposite corners of the new box.

Comment: please add an image of how you want the boxes to look at the end... this is rule #1 in stack overflow : show your desired output

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite I've depicted my expectation now.

Comment: Is your origin at the top-left or bottom-left?

Comment: This surely won't work for just the (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) coordinates of your rectangles. You'll need to rotate all four coordinates and pick then pick the max/min.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Origin is at the top left.

Comment: @xnx I've edited the code to account for all 4 corners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of your signs are wrong.

Instead of this:

```
x1new = xc + (x1-xc) * np.cos(theta) - (y1-yc)*np.sin(theta)
y1new = yc - (x1-xc) * np.sin(theta) + (y1-yc)*np.cos(theta)
```

You want this (since your origin is at the top-left):

```
x1new = xc + (x1-xc) * np.cos(theta) + (y1-yc)*np.sin(theta)
y1new = yc - (x1-xc) * np.sin(theta) + (y1-yc)*np.cos(theta)
```

I find that the easiest way to get this right in whichever coordinate system you're using is to assume a small rotation, visualize the new direction of the x axis **(cos ϴ, -sin ϴ) = (big, -small)** and make sure you're mapping a **(1,0)** vector onto that. Then visualize the new direction of the y axis **(sin ϴ, cos ϴ) = (small, big)** and make sure you're mapping a **(0,1)** vector onto that.

Comment: Additionally, you will make your life much easier if you use transformation matrices. Then you have a matrix, `toCtr = np.array([[1,0,-xc],[0,1,-yc],[0,0,1]])` and `R = np.array([[np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta), 0],[-np.sin(theta), no.cos(theta), 0],[0,0,1])` then your transformation is `M = np.linalg.inv(toCtr).dot(R).dot(toCtr)`, then just use `M.dot((x1,y1,1))[:2]`.